Reset expanded rows on page change i,e pagination `react-data-table-component`
I have enabled expandable rows functionality in react-data-table-component. I also have added pagination in the table.
Now when i expand a row say row no 3. And if i move from page no 1=>2, then on page 2, row no 3 is already expanded.
I don't expect it to be already expanded.
<DataTable
        className="custom-rows"
        progressPending={loader}
        progressComponent={<OverlayLoader />}
        columns={columns}
        data={tableData}
        pagination
        paginationServer
        paginationTotalRows={filteredItems.length}
        paginationPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50]}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        subHeader
        subHeaderComponent={subHeaderComponentMemo}
        expandableRows={true} 
        expandableRowsComponent={(row)=>{
          return <AuditTrail logData={row?.data}/>
        }}
/>

